# create a specific number of bytes from a string

Tags: java, serial-port

I would like to know if there is a way to create a specific number of bytes from a string.
I am trying to unit test some part of my code and it can take an array of bytes or a string.
But the data that I am getting will consist exactly 132 bytes (where each data point is two byte signed integers that uses 2's complement).

The data I am retrieving will consist of multiple data points in the above bytes where each data point is 2bytes.

I am planning to unit test my code. So I would like to create a string and convert to byte array and pass it so that I can cross check my data points again.

Also are there any tools available by which I can send binary data via a com port. I was looking at eltima software serial port.

Comment: `signed integers` why would you need negative numbers to encode your characters?

Comment: A `String` is a sequence of UTF-16 code-points, representing text data. You shouldn't use it to represent random byte-sequences.

Comment: @ Peter .... this was the way device was sending data. its sending data in binary which will be converted into 132 bytes of information which I    convert back to data I need. Since there are multiple data points in these 132 bytes, I want something readable then convert it into bytes and send it.

Comment: @ruakh Is he/she asking for a `random` byte sequence though?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: "Random" as in "arbitrary", not necessarily as in "generated by a pseudo-random number generator".

Comment: Did you try to store your data in an hexadecimal string and to convert to byte ? By the way you could also write the 132 octets is an external binary resource used by your test.

Answer (score 0):

there is this way which I am doing, but looking for more easy way...

```
final String MACID = new Character((char) 48).toString();
final String STX = new Character((char) 2).toString();
final String str = MACID + STX;
final byte[] utf8Bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

this would surely just take 2 bytes.

Comment: A `char` or `Character` in Java is a UTF-16 code-unit, which at heart is a two-byte unsigned integer. If you want an array of two-byte *signed* integers, use `short[]`.